# Perpendicular ridging issues when finishing drywall joints

Tags: drywall

Occasionally I have issues finishing drywall joints and will end up with a ridge or high spot at right angles to the joint itself. Looking at the seem head on in even lighting it looks perfect, but from the side with side lighting you can see the problem.

Is this typically an issue of the angle of the drywall trowel or the amount of mud I’m trying to smooth out with final pass or something else? I am a DIY homeowner but have finished most of the walls in my home and most is quite good.

Also, any suggestions for correcting the issue after the fact? It would seem that if I simply try another layer of mud, the finish trowel will still have a tendency to ride over the hump/ridge and not even it out.

Answer (score 1):

A rise in the path of the trowel or knife usually indicates an obstruction--a bump in the previous application, damaged drywall, a fastener left proud, or debris in the fresh joint compound--over which the tool rides. To prevent this...

- Scrape between applications to remove such bumps. If you hear your tool hit nails or screws, run them in or remove them. Slice off any damaged drywall paper.
- Never return contaminated compound to your bucket. Use it up as rough fill or discard it.
- Keep the bucket walls clean. Mud left on the wall will dry and contaminate the rest.
- Clean your tools thoroughly between uses.

After the fact... scrape along the ridge to remove it, or use a sanding screen.